# Make UITableViewCell width equal to UITTableView

Tags: ios, uitableview

I have a table view controller with a background image and transparent cells so you can see the image. How can I make the darker grey bits on the left and right edges to be the same brightness as the rest of the cell? I tried setting the cell's indentation width from the default of 10 to 0 which didn't help. I checked all frames and bounds in viewDidLoad and they all start at (0,0).

[Table View Controller cells](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wedWe.png)

Answer (score 0):

First of all, do not use `frame` inside `viewDidLoad`. `viewDidLoad` just informs you that "the view of the this View Controller has just been loaded, from storyboard or in code"

Instead, you need to use `frame` inside `viewDidAppear` or `viewDidLayoutSubviews`

About your problem, if you're in iOS 9, then `cellLayoutMarginsFollowReadableWidth = false`. This is for readable content guide, which is not what you want

Comment: First of all, I had a screen shot in my original post but I don't see it. Do you see it? If not, I'll try again.

Secondly, where do I put cellLayoutMarginsFollowReadableWidth? I tried it in viewDidLayoutSubviews(), viewDidLoad() and tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath(), but I still don't get the cells to be as wide as the screen. Maybe they're technically as wide, but there are about 20 pixels each on the left and right that are not the same color as the main part of the cells.

Comment: By "not the same color" I mean that they have the same color, but they appear to have a different level of transparency. The edges seem more transparent, yielding a darker appearance. Again, about 20 pixels on the left and 20 on the right.

Answer (score 0):

I got it! In the main storyboard I had to change "table view cell --> view --> background" to the clear color. I previously had 2 cell prototypes, one for odd and one for even, each with a different background color. Now, since the background color has to be clear, I use one cell prototype and change the color to white or 95% grey (and alpha of 0.5 for both) in tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath() based on whether the indexPath.row is odd or even.